# Changing assembly name broke xaml namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-assembly

I have some application named `Application.exe`. I use it for showing a different type of documents. Each document type template is a single dll-file with wpf user controls and business logic inside. So when I started my application, I download xml-file and `Template.dll` and then I show some wfp-form for work. 
My `Application.exe` and `Template.dll` both use some assembly named `Application.CustomControls.dll`. I include it in setup project for application, so `Application.CustomControls.dll` is already in the application domain when my `Application.exe` tries to show the document.

Now my client demands to change `Application.CustomControls.dll` name to `CustomControls.dll`. Don't ask, please. Just assembly's file name, not namespace or something. 
I can do it for application without problems. I can rebuild a solution and create setup project with newly named dll-file. But I can't open old templates case they all have old name inside. Especially in xaml like:

```
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:CustomControls.Design;assembly=Application.CustomControls"
```

I can't just rebuild all templates. It will be done, but in prod, there is always will be the time when some users forgot to upgrade their soft and so on. So either old application couldn't open the new template, or new application couldn't open an old template. 
I didn't change namespace, or version of `Application.CustomControls.dll` just name. Could I somehow resolve these problems and rebind assembly link inside the application? With `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event or config-file?

Comment: Can't you include both `Application.CustomControls.dll` and `CustomControls.dll` where the latter is a copy of the first one with a different name?

Comment: @mm8 No. Project "Application.CustomControls" in my solution now save as Debug(Release)\CustomControls.dll and I Include this project in Application.exe as project reference. 
I tried add "Application.CustomControls.dll", but I just had an error "A reference to "Application.CustomControls.dll" could not be added. A reference to the component "Application.CustomControls" already exists in the project".

Comment: Replace "Application.CustomControls" with "CustomControls" in your XAMl files then?

Comment: @mm8 And it is exactly my problems. I need replace code in xaml, rebuild Template.dll and upload it on server. Uploading is not my work, I can't control when and how it will be done. In the same time I need create new version Application.exe and somehow force all users (in differens offices) update their soft. It is also problem even with minor updates. Some users will try to open new templates with and old application and reverse. If there is a way to catch a call for old dll and replace it with the new one in Application.exe, I could get some free time for changing old code inside Templates